# How to force-navigate in UWP WebView to HTTPS web page with invalid/selfsigned certificate?

Tags: webview, https, windows-runtime, uwp

Let's say I want to develop my own lightweight browser Store app for Windows 10 UWP. There will be TextBox for the Uri, Button for navigation and WebView for the rest of the page.
When I navigate to HTTPS web page with valid certificate and valid TLS settings, it just works, but when I navigate to page with invalid/expired/selfsigned certificate like https://expired.badssl.com/, I only got **OnNavigationFailed** event with **WebErrorStatus.CertificateIsInvalid**.
I found no mechanism for overriding this error and continue navigation, just like it's possible in standard browsers and even in Microsoft Edge, that should be built using the same UWP API.

Is there a way, how to override the HTTPS error and navigate to the target page anyway? I know that there are security consideration, I just want to be able to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/05/including-self-signed-certificates-with-your-windows-runtime-based-windows-phone-8-1-apps.aspx

Comment: That's not a solution, I want any HTTPS site with invalid certificate to load and show in WebView.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that by design currently from what I can tell. Generally speaking, it's not safe to navigate to a page and ignore invalid certificates. It defeats the purpose. While I can see value in a debug only mode ..., Microsoft hasn't chosen to make that available.

Comment: Microsoft is able to navigate to HTTPS page with invalid certificate in the Edge browser, that should be based on the same UWP API.

Comment: The user is in control in that case, so I don't see it as the same thing exactly. But, regardless, I don't think it's a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I had to find my own solution for the problem.
The easiest solution is when connecting to specific web with self-signed certificate, it's possible to **whitelist this certificate in App Manifest** and the page will just load.
In other cases it's possible to use **WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri** method with custom **IUriToStreamResolver** that uses HttpClient with HttpBaseProtocolFilter  ignoring specified certificate validation errors. This HttpClient is then used for downloading all requested resources without errors.

More details including code sample is available here:
https://www.suchan.cz/2015/10/displaying-https-page-with-invalid-certificate-in-uwp-webview/